# How to extract haml code into helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

if I want to move the following code into helper

```
      %td.center= log.streaming_verification_id
      %td.center= log.id
```

and render it by calling `call_the_helper`

How to write the method `call_the_helper` to meet my requirement

into helper

```
  - @tool_cvt_streaming_verification_logs.each do |log|
    %tr
      = call_the_helper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply to do it by moving the code into an other view (partial), and render it from helper or another view.

view:

```
- @tool_cvt_streaming_verification_logs.each do |log|
  %tr
    = call_the_helper(log)
```

helper:

```
def call_the_helper(log)
    render partial: 'partial_view', locals: { :log => log }
end
```

partial view:

```
%td.center= log.streaming_verification_id
%td.center= log.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Put something like it in your `def call_the_helper`:

```
haml_tag :td, :class => 'center' do
  log.streaming_verification_id
end
haml_tag :td, :class => 'center' do
  log.id
end
```

Comment: Nowadays you may need something like `haml_concat log.id` to render the text, but the general approach is still good.